# Power Point Event

Tags: vb.net, powerpoint, powerpoint-2010, powerpoint-2007

Is there any type of Event in Power point that should be handled when there is changed occurred in Text Box and I click Any where in Power Point Except Text Box and It Should exist in 2007 , 2010, 2013 and above.

I handled windowslectionChange but it is not handled when click on menu

Comment: WindowSelectionChange wouldn't fire when you click a menu item because clicking a menu item doesn't change the selection (if it did, none of the menu items that refer to the currently selected object would work).  What's the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Again,  what are you trying to accomplish?  What's the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: I don't think that'll be possible.  And does it even make sense?  Update the chart every time the user clicks anything?  Wouldn't it make more sense to update the chart when the user clicks the chart in question?

Comment: Trap the selection change event.  If the current selection is your text box, set a flag variable to True.  If the current selection is not the text box and the flag variable is True, then the user has selected the text box then selected something else.  Update the chart.  However, I don't think you'll be able to force an update if the user does something on the menu with the text box selected; the selection won't change.